# I can not open my SQL code on Postgres and no error message was returned

Tags: sql, postgresql, debugging

As the title, I was unable to open my SQL code in Postgres, here are my codes:

```
DROP view ChampionList CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE ChampionList (

ChampID integer,
ChampName TEXT,

CONSTRAINT ChampionList_PK PRIMARY KEY (ChampID),

);

INSERT INTO ChampionList VALUES (1, 'Volibear');
INSERT INTO ChampionList VALUES (2, 'Lux');
INSERT INTO ChampionList VALUES (3, 'Caitlyn');
INSERT INTO ChampionList VALUES (4, 'Vel Koz');
```

I have tried multiple times but still can not open the table. Postgres also did not respond with an error message. I googled but was unable to figure out why. Here are my attempts:

[image]

Comment: I tested this on my PostgreSQL server. I got plenty of errors according to missing view, illegal creation-syntax and missing tables respectivly. I guess there is a empty `test.txt` that does not contain your codes.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! What does an empty file name mean? And how do I make sure the file contain my codes?

Comment: What system are you using? Linux Unix Windows Mac?